# How do I fix 'cannot initialize a variable of type int*' error when using 2D arrays in C++?

Tags: c++

I am getting this error for this code:

> Cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an lvalue of type 'int[3][3]'

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int mat_1[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int mat_2[3][3]={10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18};
    int dest_mat[3][3];
    int *ptr_1 = mat_1;
    int *ptr_2 =mat_2;
    int *ptr_3=dest_mat;
```

I am expecting to just create a pointer for each of the following. I even tried placing the ampersand (`&`) before the matrix names, but still no different.

Comment: Your type is wrong, try this `int (*ptr_1)[3] = mat_1;` You cannot make a `int*` pointing to a 2D array (unless you cast).

Comment: How do you intend to use the pointers? If you only want to handle one row at a time, use `int *ptr_1 = mat_1[0];`. If you want to handle the full 2D arrays, use @john code.

Comment: @273K the array initializations that are shown in the OP's code are not optimal, but they are not wrong, either. The syntax is valid, see [Array Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization), in particular the section on [Nested arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization#Nested_arrays).

Comment: Alternative: `decltype(mat_1)* ptr_1 = &mat_1;`

Answer (score 3):

In most contexts, when you refer to an array by its name alone, it *decays* into a pointer to its 1st element.

`mat_1` is an array of 3 elements, where each element is an array of 3 `int`s.  So, when you do:

`int *ptr_1 = mat_1;`

`mat_1` *decays* into a pointer to its 1st element, ie a pointer to an `int[3]` array (aka `int(*)[3]`).  A pointer to an array is a very different type than a pointer to a single `int`, thus the error you are seeing.

Same with `ptr_2` and `ptr_3`.

Depending on what you are attempting to accomplish, you need to either:

- assign `ptr_1` (and `ptr_2` and `ptr_3`) the address of the 1st `int` of the 1st array element, eg:

  `int *ptr_1 = &mat_1[0][0];`

  which can be simplified as follows (letting the inner array decay):

  `int *ptr_1 = mat_1[0];`
- change the type of `ptr_1` (and `ptr_2` and `ptr_3`) to be a pointer to an array of `int`s, not a pointer to a single `int`, eg:

  `int (*ptr_1)[3] = mat_1;`